# Will my site get messed up when the wordpress theme updates if I edited the html code in the editor to change footer?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I am trying to change the footer of my wordpress theme.

I have seen videos where they change the html code right in the editor. This seems like an easy way rather than creating child themes. I am not tech savvy.

My question what happens when the said theme updates? Will my site get messed up because I changed the code right in the editor? 
Or will it just require me to again do the same html editing in the editor each time the theme updates?

Comment: Yes it will change, you need to do it again if you are changing the theme code.

Answer (score 2):

Save the code you edit to your computer. When you update the theme, make the same edits again.

I highly discourage this practice, but it works.

Most "savy" tech dudes use "git", or other similar versioning software practices to keep from having to do this. Also, as you have stated, a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) could exist, eliminating most worries of this.

Yes, if you update the code through the [editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen), it **will be removed on update**.

Comment: hey thanks for info! Another question, when the theme updates, my other parts of the site will remain the same right (only the footer part appears again)? I am worried that when I mess with the code in the editor, then on the next update, the other parts of the site get messed up or something.

Comment: Depends on what has changes in the theme I suppose.